# How to prevent autoformat date in spreadsheet using app script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I run a third app and using spreadsheet as database. It runs normally until if I input the date 1 until 12 the date column (kolom tanggal) will automatically read the data as date and this cause the next data will not return normally as you can see in the video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SYttNUVKsrKU8Bvlh7DFQcQnaRpsXqgu/view?usp=sharing)

And in case you can't open the video:

The data return from third app as multiline text in spreassheet as shown below for example:
| timestamp | User | Tanggal | Kelas | Nama Siswa | Keterangan |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| ts1 
 ts1  | user1 
user1   | 27/3/2024
27/3/2024 |class1
class1|name1
name2|info1
info2|

image of raw data table above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Wz3.png

then app script will split the data with the result like this:
| timestamp | User | Tanggal | Kelas | Nama Siswa | Keterangan |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| ts1  | user1   | 27/3/2024 |class1|name1|info1|
| ts1  | user1   | 27/3/2024 |class1|name2|info2|

image of result table above:https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9aXJ.png

but if I choose the date from day 1 until day 12 of month (for example 1 March 2024 (1/3/2024)), the data did split but automatically formatted as date.

| timestamp | User | Tanggal | Kelas | Nama Siswa | Keterangan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts1 | user1 | 1/3/2024 | class1 | name1 | info1 |
| ts1 | user1 | 1/3/2024 | class1 | name2 | info2 |

This cause the next data returned doesn't split

| timestamp | User | Tanggal | Kelas | Nama Siswa | Keterangan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts1 | user1 | 1/3/2024 | class1 | name1 | info1 |
| ts1 | user1 | 1/3/2024 | class1 | name2 | info2 |
| ts1 ts1 | user1 user1 | 27/3/2024 27/3/2024 | class1 class1 | name1 name2 | info1 info2 |

I have tried to change the locale in spreadsheet setting and change the format into 'plain text' and change the date format using 'month in text' (MMM and MMMM) in the third app but it doesn't work.
I also have tried by joining the date format with single quotation mark (') in the third app but it doesn't work either.

Here's the script I use to append and split the data:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ceksheet(e);
}

function doGet(e) {
  return ceksheet(e);
}

function ceksheet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH); 
  
  //CREATE
  if (e.parameter.func == "Create") {
    var ts = e.parameter.TIMESTAMP;
    var user = e.parameter.USER;
    var tgl = e.parameter.TANGGAL;
    var kls = e.parameter.KELAS;
    var nama = e.parameter.NAMA;
    var ket = e.parameter.KETERANGAN;
    var data = false;
    var lr = sh.getLastRow();
    for(var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
      var data_ts = sh.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      if(data_ts==ts){
        data=true;
      } 
    }
    if (data){
      var result= "ID Sudah ada";
    }else{
      var rowData = sh.appendRow([ts,user,tgl,kls,nama,ket]);
      splitknot();
    }
  }  
function splitknot() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('dataabsen');

  var values = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var newValues = values.flatMap(r => {
    var temp = r.map(c => c.split("\n").map(d => d.trim()));
    var maxLen = Math.max(...temp.map(e => e.length));
    temp = temp.map(e => e.length < maxLen ? [...e, Array(maxLen - e.length).fill(null)] : e);
    return temp[0].map((_, col) => temp.map((row) => row[col] || null));
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length).clearContent().setValues(newValues);
  }
}
```

Kindly need your help